# My component is rendered initially after configured code splitting

Tags: react-router, webpack-2

I used webpack@beta and react-router@3.0.0, configured code splitting with react-router document .

After configured, my component is rendered initially.

My component will fetch data on `componentDidMount`, and render the data, the initial render only display an empty div, so I only got an empty div.

One of my route like this: `<Route path="shopper-center" getComponent={() => System.import('./ShopperCenter').then(c => c.ShopperCenter)}/>`, react-router history is `browserHistory`

**UPDATE 1:**
I have tried `<Route path="shopper-center" getComponent={(nextState, cb) => System.import('./ShopperCenter').then(c => cb(null,c.ShopperCenter))}/>`, it doesn't work for me.

**UPDATE 2:**
I have another component, it just output text, so that component works fine with code-spliting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asynchronously loading the components requires you to use the [callback argument](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.1/docs/API.md#callback-signature).

```
<Route
  path="shopper-center"
  getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
    System.import('./ShopperCenter')
      // if you export default, you need to import default
      .then(c => cb(null, c.default))
  }}
  />
```

**Edit** It looks like there was a [merged pull request](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/pull/3719) that added Promise support to `getComponent`, in which case you no longer have to use the callback function.

Comment: thanks Paul, but it doesn't work for me, I have tried invoke `cb` like your provided, it just render initially, I have another `route`, it works fine, because that component just render once, like this: 
            <Route path="*" getComponent={() => System.import('./Index').then(c => c.Route404)}/>

Comment: Just to be sure, in your `ShopperCenter.js` file, you are exporting your component as `ShopperCenter` and not as `default`, correct?

Comment: For this component, I have exported as default, like this: `export default ShopperCenter;` Oh, after I changed to `c.default`, it works!

Comment: I have an index route, like this: `getIndexRoute={() => System.import('./Index').then(c => c.Index)}`, I have export `Index` in `Index.js` and also exported Index as default, it doesn't work even I use `c.Index` or `c.default`, do you know what's the reason?

Comment: Have you checked what keys are included in the imported module object?

Comment: yes, I output `c` via `console.log`, it's a object, with `Index`, `Route404`, `default`, `default` is as same as `Index`

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried the callback? I know that a Promise _should_ work, but I am curious if for some reason it is failing with `getIndexRoute`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133401/discussion-between-dawncold-and-paul-s).